# Controlling Thread Execution Time in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, timing

Is it possible to control the proportional execution time of a thread in python. For example, I have three functions F1, F2 and F3 in my program. I am calling each function with using start_new_thread in python. I want F2 thread to execute 70 percent of time while F1 and F3 should share rest of 30 percent. Is there a way to explicitly control these timings.

Comment: What's the motivation here?  Why do you want to do this, and how precise does it need to be?

Comment: that's some very low level stuff which is usually handled by the os. I doubt there is a way to controll it as precise as you want to but there might be a way to start thread with a certain priority.

Comment: Actually I am trying to parallelize code which was written by someone else. I want to  use this function (F2) while making minimum changes in the original code. The problem is if I just give the call to F2 whithout creating a thread for it, it just takes too long execute. I want to create thread for this function while assigning maximum scheduling time to complete the F2 execution asap while not hanging my program during F2 call.

Comment: Python threads are *real* OS threads. All the scheduling is left to the OS. The only way of achieving what you want is reimplementing scheduling. In which case you should add checks to your function and after a certain quantum is elapsed let the thread sleep. Doing something that will work well wont be easy and the results will probably be suboptimal. Note that OSes usually give really high priorities to interactive programs, hence there should be no need to do this for the reasons you stated(at least if you didn't actually test how it runs without your custom scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a scheduler using a priority queue and a time quantum. Not sure on the specifics for this in Python, but the concept is the same: create a Scheduler class that accepts a thread, add the thread to a priority queue with a given priority, then sleep the thread after a specified time quantum has elapsed. You can tailor the time quantum depending on the current threads priority.

This is similar to how an Operating System schedules process threads.

Comment: Ahan. Thanks!. This is a good direction forward. Prioritizing the threads. Let me explore how flexible this can be in Python.

Comment: Not a problem, hope it helps!